# how to write a two counts and the newest record in hive

Tags: sql, hive

my data format is like this

> **query    guid    result    time**

I want to write a sql like

```
select
   query,
   count(query),
   count(distinect guid),
   result 
from
   table 
group by
   query
```

second column means the number of same querys,third column means the number of the distinct guids,the fourth column means the newest result,while same query may have several results and we chose the newest result by the time.since its logic is a little complex,how can i write a sql to do all these things?

Answer (score 0):

select a.md5,a.cnt,a.wide,b.main_level from (select md5,count(md5) cnt,count(distinct guid) wide,max(time) maxtime from hive group by md5) a join hive b on a.maxtime = b.time ;